# How can i query pallet contract to give the Scale codec value of a Contract Root Storage Key

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

According to ink!:

"Storage data is always encoded with the SCALE codec. The storage API operates by storing and loading entries into and from a single storage cells, where each storage cell is accessed under its own dedicated storage key."

How can i query pallet contract to return the Scale encoded value of a contract Storage key?

I want to do this such that i can always fetch the value of a particular contract storage item without interacting with the contract itself but the blockchain pallet contract.

Think of it like how you can query a slot in Ethereum and fetch the value stored for a contract in it which is done by calculating the keys(e.g for Arrays, Maps e.t.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via a runtime API call, using the contractsApi endpoint provided by the contracts pallet.

The endpoint provides a getStorage method, where you have to specify as argument the contract address and the Contract Root Storage Key.

Check this in the docs for more info and an example: [Accessing storage items with the contractsApi runtime call API](https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-in-metadata#accessing-storage-items-with-the-contractsapi-runtime-call-api).